# .Net Framework 3.5 not showing image from webbrowser navigate

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, vb.net-2010

After hours of searching I am stumped on this problem, so I hope someone could help me out? So my program is a VERY simple concept. It's a WPF written in vb.net that uses a frame to call a page that shows a webpage image from a web browser. Now the kicker is that there is code behind the .xaml that directs the web browser to open a new browser if a link is clicked and hides the frame after 10 seconds. I got the code from here in C# and translated in in vb.

So this program works great and is written in .Net Framework 4.0. However I had another program that I wanted to integrate this code into, which is written in .Net Framework 3.5 which will not show the same output as the program that was written in .Net Framework 4.0. Frustrated I wrote two examples of this program, zipped them and uploaded them so you may download them in order to assist me.

http://simpletechss.com/1stAidApp4.zip (shows 007 image from webbpage then hides after 10 seconds.)

http://simpletechss.com/1stAidApp35.zip (does not show 007 image from webbpage, then hides after 10 seconds.) 
vb
So again I am wondering why i cannot show the 007 image from webbpage in a WPF using .Net 3.5 but can in .Net 4.0? Where the code is the same in both programs and their are no syntax errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, so I resolved my own issue. It was an .xaml with .Net Framework 3.5 issue and not vb issue. By adding NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" to <Frame> with the webpage source, the webpage source was visible after 10 seconds, like I wanted. I find this very strange seeing that the same program with .Net Framework 4.0 does not need NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" for <frame> to show the webpage link . Eh, its interesting. NOTE: will be taking zip files off host and putting on new host. Will update with links.

Comment: NEVERMIND! I was working with the .Net framework 4,so I defeated the purpose of my solution. ISSUE UNRESOLVED! Sorry!